# Widndows phone - pass fill class to another page

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I neeed to pass selected item in listbox to edit page. I'm using this code to get data from listBox, but i don't know how i can pass the class Tasks to next page.

```
  private  void HoldingItem(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

FrameworkElement element = (FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource;

  Tasks tsk = (Tasks)element.DataContext;
```

// i fill the class but i dont know hot to get data on the another page

```
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(Edit), tsk);
```

}

Page Edit - get parameter

```
     protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            this.navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e);

  testlbl.Text = e.Parameter.ToString();  //it doesnt work. I can't manage the class

        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that easy to pass objects.
You should read this article for details:
http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/how-to-pass-data-between-pages-in-windows-phone-alternatives

For complex objects you should follow this pattern:
http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-master---detail-navigation-with-repository-pattern

The basic idea is simple. You can store the object in some kind of storage (Repository), pass the Id of the object to the next page and then retrieve the object by Id from the storage.

When you're ready to navigate

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(string.Format("/Page.xaml?parameter={0}",item.Id ), UriKind.Relative));
```

And on your page read the id from the query:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    string parameterValue = NavigationContext.QueryString["parameter"];   
    int id = Int32.Parse(parameterValue);
    var yourItem = _storage.GetById(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to typecast `e.Paramater` to `Tasks` (ie.) To the type of object that you are passing.

```
 var objectFromPage1=(e.Parameter as Tasks);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should store the object somewhere in your Model and pass some identifier as parameter.

Beware that different pages arent connected and you shouldnt hand over objects directly.